# Weird characters in pry output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

When I do a normal pry session, all is fine:

```
 $ pry
[1] pry(main)> 4
=> 4
[2] pry(main)> 5
=> 5
[3] pry(main)>
```

But when I start in the rails environment, It prints some strange characters:

```
 $ pry -r ./config/environment
[1] pry(main)> 4
=> 4pry(main)> 4/23B
[2] pry(main)>
```

It looks like an ascii color code is wrong, but I don't see why...

Comment: Nope. Just a missing newline somehow. `=> 4` should have been on it'w own line, but didn't have a newline appended, so it ended up on the same line as the next prompt. This is just a bug in pry.

Comment: I think I'll post an issue on the pry github project.

Comment: But the weird thing is how it works fine without rails, but fails in a rails environment.

Comment: Yeah. I posted an issue on GitHub. Add anything you want to it: https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/630

Comment: I added a gist of work and non working gemfiles

Comment: Awsome. If I get an email from GitHub telling me it's been solved or something I'll give you a comment here.

Comment: I have a github account too, I was asking here in case it was something besides pry

Comment: I saw. Oh well. Maybe someone here can still do something.

Comment: fowl, from #pry channel, suggested to try to disable colors and see if it helps.

Comment: No, but it appears that diabling indention fixes the problem.  BTW, iterm2 on OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug that cropped up when mathn is included: https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/872